# C#, Microsoft interop, Excel numberformat problem

Tags: c#, excel, format, office-interop

I am using C# to try and format a range in Excel as numbers.
When doing this, I get the green error arrow in the corner to ask me if I want to format the column as a number.

I used the code below to format the data:

```
Excel.Range Data = currentSheet.get_Range("K2:K10", Type.Missing);
Data.NumberFormat = "0.00";
```

How do I convert the range to numbers so that excel is happy?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the code that writes your data back to excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cells are already formatted as numbers, using the [PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx) function might work:

```
Excel.Range Data = currentSheet.get_Range("K2:K10", Type.Missing);
Data.Copy(System.Type.Missing);
Data.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd,
        false, false);
```

Comment: When I used the above code all the numbers that I paste are summed with the previous numbers. So the amounts are incorrect.